# pow(); function not working in vim in C language

Tags: c, pow

/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWhlb1j.o: in function `main': basic.c:(.text+0x6e): undefined reference to` pow'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
This is the error it shows me every time I try to use pow(); in any code in C language

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: did you include math.h, and link to the math library -lm when building?

Comment: Did you read man page for `pow`?

Comment: @qrdl: How do you envision reading the man page for `pow` would help resolve a linker error?

Comment: @EricPostpischil, the version I've on my system includes the instruction _Link with -lm._ in the synopsis part.

Comment: @AProgrammer: Mine does not.

Comment: @EricPostpischil https://linux.die.net/man/3/pow says `Link with -lm`. Probably non-Linux man is missing this bit, I don't have any BSD- or System V-based OS around to check.

Comment: The NetBSD man page mentions having to use `-lm`.

Answer (score 1):

You've got to link with the math-library. Add `-lm` as argument to the compiler.